# Finding a file with vbs and the open the location folder

Tags: script, find, vbscript

is there a way to make a script in vbs (or other) that search in each hard drive partition for a file and then opens the location folder of the file if the file was found? So if I want to find the file "rand.txt" that is located in the H: drive in H:\stuff\texts\, the code looks in C:,D:,E:,F:, then if it finds it in H: it proceeds to open the folder "texts". I tried with cmd but it's not actually working for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Windows batch solution (may be a time consumpting one):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for %%G in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
   if exist %%G:\NUL (
       echo %%G: drive
       for /F "tokens=*" %%H in ('where /r %%G:\ rand.txt 2>NUL') do (

         echo %%H
         explorer.exe /e,/select,"%%~fH"

       )
     )
   )
@ENDLOCAL
@GOTO :eof
```

In place of `echo %%H` you have full path to file name...

**Edit**: `where /r %%G:\ rand.txt 2>NUL` (important: `2>NUL`) to eliminate error messages `ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified` if starting directory does not exist and `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)` as in next examples (fragmentary enumeration):

```
d:\xxx>where /r C:\bat\ randx.txt
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.

d:\xxx>echo %errorlevel%
2

d:\xxx>where /r d:\bat\ randx.txt
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

d:\xxx>echo %errorlevel%
1

d:\xxx>where /r d:\bat\ rand.txt
d:\bat\files\rand.txt

d:\xxx>echo %errorlevel%
0

d:\xxx>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it in Powershell:

```
gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object -expand DeviceID | %{$drive = $_; $drive; ls "$drive\rand.txt" -recurse | %{ii (Split-Path $_)}}
```